# Google Sheets: DSUM—Not boolean in manual criteria

Tags: google-sheets

DSUM has the following syntax:

```
=DSUM(database, field, criteria)
```

in the criteria argument you can either pass a range or a manual criteria in the `{'field';'value'}` format. The sum operation happens on the field if criteria returns true. However is there a way to make it work when a criteria is false.

Comment: You either reverse the logic of the criteria. Also you could just *subtract* the original sum from the unconditional sum of cells.

Comment: @pnuts for example, a value does not exist in the range. Ed nelson's answer solved my problem. I wish Google's docs had clearly explained this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For example, if you have A-C columns and column B (No2) has nunbers and column C (answer) has "yes", "no", "maybe", this will sum rows without "yes"

```
=DSUM(A1:C4,"No2",{"answer";"<>yes"})
```

Comment: @pnuts You are correct. Answer changed to remove &.

Comment: If this doesn't work for anyone, try adding an * at the end of the string - so "<>yes*" - that will take care of any trailing whitespace